# Psychology / heuristics of $\Pr(A)\le \Pr(B)$ when $A$ is a subset of $B$

Tags: probability, psychology, philosophical

A while ago I read about the flaws people have in assigning probabilities to events based on their beliefs and experiences. For some reason, I started thinking about that today, and realized that I don't recall the main points of the argument, and really want to understand it.

I'll try to state it here as I recall it. Do you see any obvious errors in the questions or in my conclusion?

```
R = all rock stars
M = all rock stars who are Grand Masters (GM) in chess
```

What is the probability of a rock star to play chess after concert?
Doesn't seem likely, right? Say,

$\Pr(R) = 0.2$

What is the probability of a GM rock star to play chess after concert?
A lot more likely:

$\Pr(M) = 0.8$

But, $\Pr(R)$ must be $> \Pr(M)$ as $M$ is a subset of $R$, right? So one or both of the probabilities has to be wrong.

1. So, does this mean I have to modify $\Pr(R), \Pr(M)$ or both?
2. Or in order to have said $0.2$ I had to know the size of $M$?
3. Or is there a problem with how the question is stated?

Also, if you can point me to a book or a paper on the subject, I'd really appreciate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do you see any obvious errors in the questions or in my conclusion?
>
> R = all rock stars
> M = all rock stars who are Grand Masters (GM) in chess

Starting at the most basic, you should define your events as events (sets of *outcomes*), rather than sets containing all members for whom the event is true.

Like this:

Let $R$ be the event "is a rock star"

Let $M$ be the event "is a rock star who is a Grand Master in chess"

> What is the probability of a rock star to play chess after concert? Doesn't seem likely, right? Say,
>
> Pr(R)=0.2

The problem right here is you have changed the meaning of the event R. You're trying to talk about the probability that a rock star plays chess after a concert. That is, you need to define a new event:

Let $C$ be the event "plays chess after a concert"

Then you can properly define your probability, which I presume to be a conditional probability:

$P(C|R)=0.2$

"*Given someone is a rock star, the chance they play chess after a concert is 0.2*"

This is easier to read left to right if you say it as:

"*The chance someone plays chess after a concert given they're a rock star is 0.2*"

(it's a little awkward phrased that way in this case, because we introduce 'after a concert' before we know this is someone for whom that's even possible, which makes the English phrasing seem odd. Usually it works just fine this way though.)

Similarly

$P(C|M)=0.8$

> But, Pr(R) must be >Pr(M) as M is a subset of R, right?

Right, and now it can be, because we're not confounding it with something else.

You can, for example, talk about $P(M|R)$ being small, or that $P(M\cap C)<P(R\cap C)$

($\cap$ works like it always does with sets, being an intersection; read it out as 'and'; many people write that instead as $P(M C)<P(R C)$)

$ $

You have to be very careful about defining your events and distinguishing conditional probabilities (like $P(C|M)$) from joint probabilities (like $P(C\cap M)$).

---

As for the psychology of people's assessment of such things, people seem to think in terms of *stories*, or *scenarios*.

The *story* of "a rock star grand master who plays chess after a concert" works as a tale.

The *story* of "a rock star who plays chess after a concert" doesn't.

This causes people to tend to internally (but not explicitly) confound the concept relating to the conditional event $(C|M)$ with the one relating to the compound event $(CM)$ and hence regard $P(CM)$ as more likely than $P(CR)$ even though the event $CM$ is a proper subset of $CR$.